# CViewAction don't work

Tags: php, yii

I created controller:

```
class WebsiteController extends  Controller
{

    public function actions(){
        return array(
            'page'=>array('class'=>'CViewAction')

        ) ;
    }
```

in **protected\views\website\pages** I created file 
login.php

```
 <h1>Hello</h1>
```

**index.php?r=website/page&view=login**  not view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yii works as index.php?r=controller/action i.e. index.php?r=site/login that's mean there is a controller name SiteController which have action method login. Please check in folder protected/controller. In the SiteController::actionLogin, you will find `$this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));` which render the login's view page. Please check in folder protected/views/site/login.php.

So if you would like to create controller name Website,

- create WebsiteController.php in the folder protected/controller
- create view file index.php in protected/views/website/
- write the following code in protected/controller/WebsiteController.php

---

```
class WebsiteController extends Controller
{
public function actionIndex()
{
    $this->render('index');
}
}
```

---

- write the following code in protected/controller/views/index.php

---

```
<h1>Hello Yii</h1>
```

- Now go to the browser type the link http://localhost/[your site name]/index.php?r=website/index

Furthermore, learn more about yii from http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app and also http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/

Answer (score 0):

Yii Blog  sample has the same code for SiteController

```
public function actions(){
    return array(
        'page'=>array('class'=>'CViewAction')

    ) ;
}
```

and in view/site folder has a subfolder named page where is about.php file so if is needed some static pages how to work with them?